# C programming : how to create a game board with tokens in each cell?

Tags: c

I am creating a game board with tokens on it for an exercise.
Its a 9x9 board which I have already created but I am having problems with adding the tokens into each cell. Whenever I add in my code for the tokens it screws up the format of my game board. 
I am fairly new to C, so sorry if this might be a stupid question, but I have tried searching and fixing it myself but had no luck so far. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code for the gameboard:

```
int x,y; 

for (x=0; x<9; x++)
{ 
    printf (" +"); 
    for (y=0; y<9; y++)  
      printf("---+"); 
    printf ("\n%d", x+1); 
    printf (" |"); 
    for (y=0; y<9; y++) 
      printf(" |"); 
    printf ("\n"); 
} 
printf (" +"); 
for (y=0; y<9; y++) 
  for (y=0; y<9; y++) 
    printf("---+"); 
printf ("\n");
```

This is my code to display the tokens:

```
for(x=0; x<9; x++)
{
    printf(" ");
    switch(board[y][x])
    {
        case PEG:
            printf("o");
            break;
        case HOLE:
            printf(".");
            break;
        case INVALID:
            printf(" ");
    }
}
```

I need "o" to display in all cells, and "." display only in the middle cell.

This is the board that I have created:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |  
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Please show the definition and initialization of `board`.

Comment: Paste the pattern which you are looking at

Comment: you can use `goto(x,y)` in console environment ! google it.

Comment: If you're new to C, you really should make the extra effort to properly indent your code and, with loops, enclose all the instructions between curly brackets, even if their is only one instruction. It helps loads to clarify things, and you may even be able to find the mistake yourself.

Comment: Use conditional statement, to condition your printf statement as when it has value in middle cell then print "." else "0".

Answer (score 2):

You can't first print the board outline/borders, then print the contents. You need to do them "interleaved", so that you don't mess up the current cursor position.

One way of doing this is to iterate for more than the board's dimensions, i.e. instead od 9x9, iterate over an 11x11 area, and use `if` to check if the current location is in the board or on the border.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below:

```
     #include <stdio.h>
        int main(void) {
        int a[9][9];
        int i,j,k;
        for(i=0;i<9;i++) 
        printf("+---");


        printf("+\n");
        memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
        for(i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<9;j++)
            {
              if( i == 4 && i==j )
            printf("| . ");
            else
            printf("| %d ",a[i][j]);
            }
            printf("|\n");
            for(k=0;k<9;k++) 
            printf("+---");

            printf("+\n");
        }

        return 0;
      }
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | . | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```